# White blank screen in iPhone simulator and Black blank screen when loaded into iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I run my app on the simulator, every time a white blank screen would be generated. but after I black iPhone button on the bottom to exit the app, the views will then be visible after you re-enter the app. then the app run as usual.

But the situation is different when I load it into my iPhone.
Only BLACK blank screen can be seen into the app. after I exit the app and re-enter it, still nothing can be seen, and the app would automatically exit, too.

I dunno why it would be like that as simulator just simulate the real iPhone.

Here is some information:

iOS version of my iPhone: iOS 5
XCode version: XCode 4.2

Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's a simulator, not an emulator. There are some subtle differences. Clearly you've found one. I can't quite understand your question, maybe you could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Base SDK is as high or higher than your current version.  Change it in your target settings and your project settings.  Also change your compiler to Apple LLVM and your debugger (under edit scheme) to LLDB.